# Visual Studio 2008 ProjectTemplates

Tags: visual-studio, project-template

Is there anywhere I can download the ProjectTemplates folder for Visual Studio 2008? I accidently deleted it and the cache folder so need to get a copy of it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using installation repair?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this from the Visual Studio Command Prompt. It should allow you to fix the problem without going through the installation repair process.

```
devenv /installvstemplates
```